# An 80s/90s tv miniseries about kids travelling across dimensions or in time?

Tags: story-identification

There was a boy and a girl, and they had a small puppet creature with the name of Prism, and at the end it turned into an actual prism of crystal on a necklace, I think. Near the end, it might be that their ship was being eaten by multiplying slug puppets?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Please don't VTC as a dupe of a question which is itself a dupe. I'm closing this instead as a dupe of the question that *that's* a dupe of, which isn't a dupe itself.

Comment: That kind of makes sense. The one I linked was a lot more detailed, so it seemed to make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Josh Kirby... Time Warrior](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113484/)*

From a review on IMDB:

> Storyline is definitely for juveniles: Josh encounters time traveling pod and its occupants (Irwin, Azebeth & Prism) and is pursued by Dr. Zoetrope who is trying to obtain the **crystal pieces** of a time nullifier device. At least the ending (in episode 6) has a twist. Azabeth is a headstrong girl who eventually likes Josh. **Prism is a cute little alien who reminds me of a cross between gremlins & yoda**. Irwin is the professor running the time pod trying to get the nullifier pieces before Zoetrope can. Each episode leads into the next just like old time serials did.

In the sixth episode, Josh meets a girl with the prism on her necklace (played by a young Charisma Carpenter!). The slug puppets is probably from the fourth episode, "Time Warrior- Eggs From 70 Million B.C."

[image: Slugs]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. One of these days, I've got to watch that one... it keeps coming up around here.